# How to properly type a mocked module?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Is there a less verbose way of **typing** a mocked module than having to use `as` ?

```
import { fetchUsers } from './services/usesService';
jest.mock('./services/userService');

describe('something', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    (fetchBrief as jest.Mock).mockClear(); // this works
    fetchUsers.mockClear(); // Property 'mockClear' does not exist on type...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but not really since it's still verbose, but I'll use `as` if I have too

Comment: There are numerous answers with various approaches, but the point is more to drive any additional answers to that same place so they're all together. In cases like this it's better to get attention with a bounty, otherwise the answers end up scattered all around the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having success overwriting the module's methods with mocks manually and `ts` plays super nice with them:

```
import * as userService from './services/usesService';

const fetchUsersMock = jest.mock();
const fetchBriefMock = jest.mock();

userService.fetchUsers = fetchUsersMock;
userService.fetchBrief = fetchBriefMock;

describe('something', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchBriefMock.mockClear();
    fetchUsers.mockClear();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a nice solution